# Parallel route modal using Next.js 13's App Router returns 404 on refresh

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components, app-router

I'm trying building modal using parallel routes in Next.js `13.4`.

It works when I'm on the homepage (`/`) and open the modal (push to `/login`).

But when I refresh the `/login` page, instead of showing homepage with modal, it shows the `404` page with the modal:

[image: 404 not found with modal above]

This is my folder structure:

[image: Project folder structure]

This is `@overlays/login/page.tsx`:

```
'use client';

import {useRouter} from 'next/navigation';
import {Dialog} from '@mui/material';

export default function Page() {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
       <Dialog
          open
          onClose={router.back}
          keepMounted
          disablePortal
       >
          Hello
       </Dialog>
    );
}
```

Could you tell me how to render the home page (`/`) when navigating directly on parallel route `/login`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get rid of the `404`, you are probably missing `@overlays/default.tsx`:

```
export default function Default() {
  return null;
};
```

It's explained in the docs for [Parallel Routes > Unmatched Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes#unmatched-routes):

> **Unmatched Routes**
>
> By default, the content rendered within a slot will match the current URL.
>
> In the case of an unmatched slot, the content that Next.js renders differs based on the routing technique and folder structure.
>
> [...]
>
> **Reload**
>
> On reload, Next.js will first try to render the unmatched slot's default.js file. If that's not available, a 404 gets rendered.

Based on your last question, it looks like you don't want the modal to be accessible as a standalone page, which is what [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes) seems to consider one of the main use cases for this:

> Other examples could include opening a login modal in a top navbar while also having a dedicated `/login` page, or opening a shopping cart in a side modal.

If you want `/login` to redirect to `/` when directly accessed, your might want to use [router interception](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes) to render a different component in that case, which can then just call [`redirect('/')`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect), so you should end up with the following files:

```
app
  (home)
  login
    page.tsx <= LoginPage
  @overlays
    login
      page.tsx <= LoginModal
    page.tsx
```

And `login/page.tsx` looks something like this:

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

export default function LoginPage() {
  redirect('/')

  return null;
};
```

Comment: You got wrong I guess. Main reason of having login or signup in separate page is any user can directly navigate to our login page, www.xyz.com/login. in this case even if we declared default.js, it throwing error. this should not be the case. it should open login modal. can you help me with that?

Comment: Thank you @danziger, I was able to solve my issue with your help